# Procedure for exception handling (catch, log, report, fix) in end user desktop app

Tags: .net, logging, exception, aop, desktop-application

I'm starting a new project, a end-user desktop application. I'm a concerned about what will happened if (ok, when) the end-user gets an unhandled exception. 
Asking the user to help me reproduce the bug is not an acceptable option. 
As I see it I'm left with one option: to upload an error report to my server.

Years ago when I were a Delphi developer, a great tool called madExcept could help me with all this, but I cannot find a similar tool on the .Net framework. So I guess I have to make my own.

Here is my idea

- Use a log-framework and write a few
  well thought log entries, not too
  many or few. Just log to memory,
  better performance and I don't need
  the file. Limit the log size to say 100KB.
- Use AOP to log parameters and return values on all methods, except those in a tight loop as it will clutter the log and cause bad performance. This is the point I'm really insecure about, is this a stupid thing to do in production? The benefit seems very appealing though. I think I should be able to reproduce the exception in a lot more cases, than having just a stack trace and a log. Also this will logged to a memory and limited to something like 200KB.
- Catch all unhandled exceptions, here I will upload the two logs and stack trace to my server.

What do you think will it work? Is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: I just fell over http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com, this looks interresting

Comment: The question isn't getting a lot of attention, so I think I will re-ask it as a new question and focus on the AOP part.

Answer (score 1):

Do you expect to have many unhandled exceptions?

Just catch unhandled exceptions at the application level, and log them. Do catch exceptions locally when it's necessary to add additional information:

```
public void OpenConfigurationFile(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        File.Open(filePath, ...);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            String.Format("Can't open configuration file {0}", filePath), ex);
    }
}
```

That way, you'll not only log the `FileNotFoundException`, but also the fact that it was a configuration file you were trying to open.

Comment: >Do you expect to have many unhandled exceptions?---
I hope not. I would like to provide a stable application, so one is too many, if that's what you asking? I know that's not realistic to have a bug free app, but in this case I want to be better than just the acceptable.
---

Your example is good, but the exceptions I'm thinking about is not "predictable" exceptions causes by external dependencies. It's more like InvalidOperationException and NullReferenceException. Things caused by invalid logic, what I would call a bug, but people have different definitions of the word.

Comment: Are these external dependencies that you cannot test?

Comment: >Are these external dependencies that you cannot test?
Sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Ahh okay, if I get you right. You suggest that I should test my code before releasing to get a error-free app? Sure automated tests will find many bugs, but I have yet to see an error-free app no matter how many high a test coverage you have.

Comment: I suggest you do enough testing of the external dependencies to make such an elaborate logging mechanism unnecessary.

Comment: As I said, my focus here is not on external dependencies and I don't see tests as sufficient for getting a real stable system.